# How to make Chrome open a URL using ScriptingBridge in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, google-chrome, safari, scripting-bridge

I have working Objective-C code that uses ScriptingBridge to make Safari open a URL.  Something like:

```
#import "Safari.h"  /* created by executing "sdef /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app | sdp -fh --basename GoogleChrome" */
if ((safariApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"]) == nil) {
    NSLog(@"couldn't access Google Chrome");
} else {
    NSString *theUrl = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"http://www.ford.com"];
    NSDictionary *theProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:theUrl forKey:@"URL"];
    SafariDocument *doc = [[[safariApp classForScriptingClass:@"document"] alloc] initWithProperties:theProperties];
    [[safariApp documents] addObject:doc];
}
```

I'd like to create similar code that will do the same thing for Chrome instead of Safari.  Obviously I need to change "Safari.h" to "GoogleChrome.h" and "com.apple.Safari" to "com.google.Chrome".  I'm not sure how to change the last three lines - there's no definition of  "GoogleDocument" in GoogleChrome.h

Comment: Don't forget to add the ScriptingBridge framework to your project. If you don't, you'll get cryptic compiler errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
GoogleChromeApplication *application = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.google.Chrome"];
GoogleChromeWindow *window = [[[application classForScriptingClass:@"window"] alloc] initWithProperties:nil];
[application.windows addObject:window];
window.activeTab.URL = @"http://www.example.com";
[window release];
[application activate];
```

Comment: Thanks, Sean!  That works fine, so I ripped out the slow AppleScript-based workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to get what you need is with AppleScript.

```
NSString *script = @"tell application \"Google Chrome\" to \
                    open location \"http://www.ford.com\"";
NSAppleScript* appleScript = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource: script];
[appleScript executeAndReturnError:nil];
```

This works with *Safari* and *Firefox* as well (of course you need to change `\"Google Chrome\"` with `\"Safari\"` or `\"Firefox\"`).

Comment: Thank you!  The AppleScript solution works.  I can use it in my production code.  Of course, I'd still like a ScriptingBridge solution if someone knows the proper incantation.

BTW, my program needs to be able to control Safari, Chrome or Firefox.  It now has a working ScriptingBridge solution for Safari and a working AppleScript solution for Chrome.  I don't have a working solution for Firefox.  I assumed that I could just change "Google Chrome" to "Firefox" in the AppleScript solution you provided, but that doesn't work.  Ack!

Comment: I updated the code with a version that works with Firefox and Safari.